# how to pop view from stack in tab bar controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar controller. In one of the viewcontroller children I do a check and determine if I will show a login view with this code:

```
if(loggedIn){

}else{

    SignupViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignupView"];
    svc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

}
```

From here the user goes through several subsequent views in wizard format. Like from SignupViewController1->SignupViewController2->SignupViewController3->etc. As @Rocky pointed out, you cannot pop SignupViewController1 off the stack while you are in SignupViewController2 or 3 or any subsequent viewController.

I know the iOS docs state the following:

> If YES, the bottom bar remains hidden until the view controller is
>   popped from the stack.

My question is how do I get acccess to the original SignupViewController to pop it off the stack to see my tabbar again once I have moved to subsequent views in its navigation controller?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a navController with a stack that looks something like this: SignupViewController1->SignupViewController2->SignupViewController3->etc. You cannot pop SignupViewController1 off the stack while you are in SignupViewController2 or 3 or any subsequent viewController.

Comment: @rocky thats exactly it.  Should I get to SignupViewController1 and then pop it from the stack?

Comment: so you can do this:  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Yeah if you want to pop SignupViewController1 you would have to pop off any other viewController that was pushed after it

Answer (score 0):

(The next answer is for SWIFT, but, you can traduce it to Objective-C)

I do not know, but maybe you can try that:

```
@IBAction func returnToPreviusScene(sender : AnyObject) {
        let navController:UINavigationController = self.navigationController!
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        navController.pushViewController(FatherView.singleton, animated: false)
    }
```

You need to know: 
`singleton` is a static variable from the VIEW `FatherView`